# mod multiplication

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, congruences

A multiplication has been performed incorrectly, but the answer is correct (mod 9), (mod 10), and (mod 11). What is the closest that the incorrect result can possibly be to the correct result?

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ is the correct and $b$ is the incorrect then $(a-b)\equiv 0\text{ mod }9,10,11$

By using Chinese Reminder Theorem, one gets $(a-b)\equiv 0\text{ mod }9\cdot 10\cdot 11=990$ (because $9$, $10$, and $11$ are relatively prime)

The closest the incorrect answer can possibly be to the correct result is $990$

Comment: yes, but you could point out that it is only true because GCD($9,10,11$)$=990=9\times10\times11$ because they are coprime.

Comment: yes, that is the case.

Comment: I know ^^ what I meant was that it should be part of the answer.

You could tell an unaware reader that you were using the chinese remainder theorem, and explain where the $990$ came from.

Comment: OK, I added as you suggested :)